# My Combobox is not populating

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am using a combo box within a datagrid, binding to a view model using WPF and MVVM.  My combo box is not populating though the data bound item does have data.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.

My first datagrid populates just fine with the cross sectional data.
My second datagrid populates with the appropriate zone data.  However, the combobox itemsource and selected cross section are not working in the second data grid.  If I set breakpoints in the property for crosssections and selected cross sections, I get to the breakpoints.  However, the data is not being populated.

I updated my code to reflect the changes suggested.  The drop down entries populated just fine, as did a selected item.  However, I noticed that I had properties with the same name in both the MainWindowViewModel and the Zone viewmodel class.  So, I updated the Zone class as below:

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Public Class Zone
   Inherits ViewModelBase

   Private _zoneNumber As Integer
   Private _selectedZoneCrossSection As CrossSection
   Private _length As Double

   Public Property ZoneNumber As Integer
      Get
         Return _zoneNumber
      End Get
      Set(value As Integer)
         _zoneNumber = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() ZoneNumber)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property SelectedZoneCrossSection As CrossSection
      Get
         Return _selectedZoneCrossSection
      End Get
      Set(value As CrossSection)
         _selectedZoneCrossSection = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() SelectedZoneCrossSection)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property Length As Double
      Get
         Return _length
      End Get
      Set(value As Double)
         _length = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Length)
      End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

I then modified the MainWindow.xaml ComboBox component as follows and now I'm working as I expected...

```
       <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Cross Section"                                        
                                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedZoneCrossSection}"                        
                           DisplayMemberPath="RecordNumber">
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CrossSections}"/>
             </Style>
          </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
          <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
             <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CrossSections}"/>
             </Style>
          </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
       </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

My MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxBinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="800">
   <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CrossSections}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCrossSection}" 
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding RecordNumber}"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Binding="{Binding Height}"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Binding="{Binding Width}"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Area" Binding="{Binding Area}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>

         <Separator/>
         <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Zones}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedZone}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding ZoneNumber}"/>
               <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Cross Section" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding CrossSections, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                                       SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedCrossSection}"
                                       DisplayMemberPath="RecordNumber"
                                       />
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My MainWindowViewModel.vb

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Public Class MainWindowViewModel
   Inherits ViewModelBase

   Private _crossSections As ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection) = New ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection)()
   Private _selectedCrossSection As CrossSection
   Private _zones As ObservableCollection(Of Zone) = New ObservableCollection(Of Zone)
   Private _selectedZone As Zone

   Public Property CrossSections As ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection)
      Get
         Return _crossSections
      End Get
      Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection))
         _crossSections = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() CrossSections)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property SelectedCrossSection As CrossSection
      Get
         Return _selectedCrossSection
      End Get
      Set(value As CrossSection)
         _selectedCrossSection = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() SelectedCrossSection)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property Zones As ObservableCollection(Of Zone)
      Get
         Return _zones
      End Get
      Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Zone))
         _zones = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Zones)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property SelectedZone As Zone
      Get
         Return _selectedZone
      End Get
      Set(value As Zone)
         _selectedZone = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() SelectedZone)
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Sub New()

      InitializeCrossSections()
      InitializeZones()

   End Sub

   Public Sub InitializeCrossSections()
      Dim oc As ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection) = New ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection)()
      Dim cs As CrossSection

      For i = 1 To 10
         cs = New CrossSection()
         cs.RecordNumber = i
         cs.Height = i
         cs.Width = i + 1
         cs.Area = cs.Height * cs.Width
         oc.Add(cs)
      Next
      CrossSections = New ObservableCollection(Of CrossSection)(oc)
      SelectedCrossSection = CrossSections(0)

   End Sub

   Public Sub InitializeZones()
      Dim oc As ObservableCollection(Of Zone) = New ObservableCollection(Of Zone)()
      Dim zn As Zone

      For i = 1 To 3
         zn = New Zone()
         zn.ZoneNumber = i
         zn.Length = 10 - i * 0.25
         zn.SelectedCrossSection = CrossSections(i)
         oc.Add(zn)
      Next
      Zones = New ObservableCollection(Of Zone)(oc)
      SelectedZone = Zones(0)
   End Sub
End Class
```

My CrossSection Class:

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Public Class CrossSection
   Inherits ViewModelBase

   Private _recordNumber As Integer
   Private _height As Double
   Private _width As Double
   Private _area As Double

   Public Property RecordNumber As Integer
      Get
         Return _recordNumber
      End Get
      Set(value As Integer)
         _recordNumber = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() RecordNumber)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property Height As Double
      Get
         Return _height
      End Get
      Set(value As Double)
         _height = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Height)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property Width As Double
      Get
         Return _width
      End Get
      Set(value As Double)
         _width = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Width)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property Area As Double
      Get
         Return _area
      End Get
      Set(value As Double)
         _area = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Area)
      End Set
   End Property

End Class
```

My Zone Class

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight

Public Class Zone
   Inherits ViewModelBase

   Private _zoneNumber As Integer
   Private _selectedCrossSection As CrossSection
   Private _length As Double

   Public Property ZoneNumber As Integer
      Get
         Return _zoneNumber
      End Get
      Set(value As Integer)
         _zoneNumber = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() ZoneNumber)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property SelectedCrossSection As CrossSection
      Get
         Return _selectedCrossSection
      End Get
      Set(value As CrossSection)
         _selectedCrossSection = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() SelectedCrossSection)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property Length As Double
      Get
         Return _length
      End Get
      Set(value As Double)
         _length = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() Length)
      End Set
   End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made few changes. Refer the below code.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CrossSections}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCrossSection}" 
               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
               >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding RecordNumber}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Binding="{Binding Height}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Binding="{Binding Width}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Area" Binding="{Binding Area}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Separator/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Zones}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedZone}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding ZoneNumber}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Cross Section"                                        
                                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SelectedCrossSection}"                        
                                   DisplayMemberPath="RecordNumber">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CrossSections}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CrossSections}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Length}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Solved the problem exactly!!  Thanks.